# jQuery and JSON: break object into a table

Tags: jquery, json, tabular

I need a little bit of help navigating through this object:

`{"COLUMNS":["ID","TYPE","NAME"],"DATA":[[1,"Image","My Image"],[2,"Text","My Text"],[3,"Video","My Video"],[4,"video","test"],[5,"Image","testName"],[6,"Image","testName"],[7,"Image","testName"],[8,"Image","testName"],[9,"Image","testName"],[10,"Image","testName"]]}`

What would be the best way to loop over this object in order to display it like so:

```
ID  | Type   | Name
1     Video    My Video
...   ...      ...
```

This JSON object is clearly a query result... a lot of queries will need to be displayed as tabular data like this, so perhaps I should create a class (function) that handles this result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
headers = obj["COLUMNS"];
$(headers).each(function(index,item){ /* do something interesting */ });
data    = obj["DATA"];
$(data).each(function(index,item){ /* do something interesting */ });
```

"Something interesting" in this case would be to create new TH and TD elements from the headers, TR and TD elements from the data rows.

(You could of course do

```
$(obj["COLUMNS"]).each(...)
```

if you don't need the headers and data separately later.  Sometimes I think people go a little overboard with the functional model, sacrificing clarity.)

Comment: Yeah, this is looking good. And by creating the table header elements, there's a lot more control available.

Answer (score 0):

So thanks to Charlie Martin, I put together a nice little function that will take the result of the query and create a table using jQuery:

```
function createTable(result) {

    var headers = result["COLUMNS"];
    var data = result["DATA"];      
    var tableHeader = "<table><thead><tr>";
    var tableBody = "<tbody>";
    var endTable = "</table>";

    $(headers).each(function(index,item){
        //alert("HEADER: " + item);

        tableHeader += "<th>" + item + "</th>";     

    });

    tableHeader += "</tr></thead>";
    $(tableHeader).appendTo("#placeholder");

    $(data).each(function(index,item){
        //alert("DATA: " + item);

        tableBody += "<tr>";

        $(item).each(function(index, secitem) {
            tableBody += "<td>" + secitem + "</td>";
        });

        tableBody += "</tr>";

    });

    tableBody += "</tbody>";

    $(tableBody).appendTo("#placeholder");              
    $(endTable).appendTo("#placeholder");

}
```

Comment: Of course, if you wanted to you could add in your CSS and make it all look purdy...

Comment: Glad you liked it.  You *could* give me a check mark for it, he hinted. :-)

Comment: By the way, you could simplify that a lot more by using the jQuery DOM manipulation functions: http://api.jquery.com/category/manipulation/

Comment: Well, I am using `appendTo` ... perhaps I could employ some more.

Comment: Basically, I'd be tempted to construct it something like `var tabl = $('<table>');` then `tabl.append($('<thead>).appendTo($(<th>).appendTo(...`.  That way you don't have the change of getting your `<tag>`s and `</tag>`s mixed up.